# Compile-time comparison of pointers to local variables after their end of life

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr

Starting from C++17, it is possible to define a `constexpr` function that will return a pointer on its local variable. The caller will so get a pointer on an object after its end of life.

Clearly such pointers cannot be dereferenced to avoid undefined behavior. But is it legal to compare them on equality?

Consider an example:

```
constexpr auto f() {
    char c = 0;
    auto p = &c;
    return p;
};

int main() {
    static_assert( ( f() == f() ) == ( f() == f() ) ); //ok everywhere
    static_assert( f() == f() ); //true in GCC, false in Clang
}
```

The first `static_assert` is accepted by all compilers (if there is some undefined behavior, no single warning appear), and it basically checks that `f() == f()` gives consistent result `true` or `false` in each compiler.

GCC says that `f() == f()` is true, while Clang insists on `f() != f()` (which looks more logical for compile-time). Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YG1jonoG7

Which compiler (if any) is right here?

Comment: I think your question is not related to what the C++ standard has to say about this. Different compilers have different implemenations, what I think this is showing is that Clang makes some other calls that result in the stack being different at the time of the second call to f() and thus c ending up on a different address. I see no problem with that.

Comment: The more interesting question is why would you want to return a pointer to a local, `constexpr` or not? The only information the pointer will provide is a relative position within the program stack frame. Maybe that is useful to you or not? The question from a standard standpoint is worthwhile. Your question appears to be an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, oddly, **implementation-defined** per [basic.stc]/4: the pointers returned by `f` are **invalid**, so comparing them might do something bad.  Of course, it’s not really clear what the space of possibilities includes here: a footnote mentions a runtime fault, which is usually lumped with undefined behavior, but during constant evaluation one would expect that to reliably **fail** the evaluation (which would be reported as “`static_assert` expression not constant”).  Supposedly, implementations are required to document their choice here, but I doubt any of them meaningfully address this particular situation.